# Python Pandas: Returning DataFrame from function yields NoneType

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple CSV files with the naming convention YYYY.csv. To merge the CSVs, I created the following recursive function to union the data frames together.

```
def createFrames(year,parent=None,lim=range(2000,2019)):
  if year in lim:
    df=pd.read_csv(str(year)+'.csv')
    df['Year']=year
    if parent is None:
      parent=df
    else:
      parent=pd.concat([parent,df])
    createFrames(year+1,parent=parent)
  else: 
    print(parent.describe)
    return parent

df=createFrames(2000)
df.head()
```

When I print the **parent.describe** from within the function, it prints the fully merged dataframe. However, when returning **parent**, the variable **df** has the type **NoneType** and is empty. Output below:

```
<bound method NDFrame.describe of      Unnamed: 0            Player   Tm  ... ReceivingTD  FantasyPoints  Year
0             0    Marshall Faulk  STL  ...         8.0         455.90  2000
1             1    Edgerrin James  IND  ...         5.0         393.30  2000
2             2  Daunte Culpepper  MIN  ...         0.0         334.48  2000
3             3       Jeff Garcia  SFO  ...         0.0         338.52  2000
4             4      Eddie George  TEN  ...         2.0         334.20  2000
..          ...               ...  ...  ...         ...            ...   ...
617         617       Kaelin Clay  NYG  ...         0.0          -2.00  2018
618         618          JJ Jones  2TM  ...         0.0          -0.70  2018
619         619     Kyle Lauletta  NYG  ...         0.0          -2.20  2018
620         620    Riley McCarron  NWE  ...         0.0          -2.00  2018
621         621       Jojo Natson  LAR  ...         0.0          -2.00  2018

[11280 rows x 29 columns]>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-119-9ea047491d15> in <module>()
     14 
     15 df=createFrames(2000)
---> 16 df.head()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

How do I return the merged dataframe from the function?

Comment: You probably forgot to put `return` in `createFrames(year+1,parent=parent)`.

Comment: Andrej, the function is recursive and the return statement is below parent.describe, which is executed.

Comment: When you do recursion, you have to return from all branches (here the `if .. else ...`). Otherwise, you return `None` at the end.